# Extract html content of webview in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, webview, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Is there any way to extract **html** of currently displayed page in **webview**?
I need to extract **html** and parse and reload again?
I tried **Htmlclienthandler** which works ok if it is simple website

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true,       AllowAutoRedirect = true };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

But page is in **OWA** email page and i am keep getting **Error:400 Bad requesr** in response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract HTML from `WebView` using `InvokeScript(...)` method.

```
string html = webview.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] {"document.documentElement.outerHTML;"});
```

Comment: You need to call the `InvokeScript/InvokeScriptAsync` in the `NavigationCompleted` event handler. The NotImplementedException is apparently thrown if `InvokeScript` is called before the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`InvokeScript` was throwing `NotImplementedException` exception but `InvokeScriptAsync` worked for me.